# what is wrong with this file"spring-config.xml"?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

The is the first time I am using spring in Intellij.

I have clicked the option `Auto create xml`,and it marked the file with an error.

Any idea what might be wrong?

[image]

Comment: check that you have spring packages somewhere in your classpath

Comment: Are you using the community edition of IntelliJ? It doesn't have special support for Spring. The ultimate edition does.

Comment: @Jesper, not community edition

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do following:

1. Download the appropriate version (X.Y) of `spring-beans.xsd-X.Y` from [here](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/).
2. In IDEA, select an option to "manually setup external resource" and follow the on screen option to locate the above xsd on your computer.

This should resolve the error.